# How to change the height of the div according to the text?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble putting height variant sizes according to the number of balloons in my div.
They are following a fixed height and are not changing size according to the text, I can't put the first balloon as a height smaller than the first balloon, I already tried for a negative margin that didn't work either.

//the html below is rendered by javascript

```css
div#chat-panel-casca {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition-delay: .6s;
  transition: .7s;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

div #chat-casca {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F4F4F6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 499px;
}


/*this stretch corresponds to a tail applied to the first balloon*/

div #chat-casca #tail {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 0 17.5px 19px 17.5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #FFFFFF transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(-6px 2px 2px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.24));
  transform: rotate(48deg);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: -32px;
  right: 19px;
}

div #chat-casca .chat-box {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 323px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12px;
  left: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
}


/*This is my main css, it is the balloon composition*/

div #chat-casca .chat-box p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div #chat-casca .chat-box .chat-time {
  position: relative;
  color: #4d4e53;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  top: -25px;
  padding-left: 293px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-panel-casca">
  <div id="chat-casca">
    <div class="chat-box">
      <p>Hy, i ame here</p>
      <div id="tail"></div>
      <small class="chat-time">9:6</small>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-box">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p> Another text.</p>
      <small class="chat-time">9:6</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to decrease the margin-botton of the first div of the example below and set the spacing of the following divs keeping the height proportion.

I have this result:

[image]

But I need this result

[image]

Comment: Hi! did you try this .chat-box {    height: max-content;} ?

Comment: try this .chat-box { line-height: 0.5rem;}

Comment: [Perhaps some of these have the answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+change+the+height+of+the+div+according+to+the+text)

Comment: I made a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it just by changing your CSS.

1. Remove vertical margins from **p** inside **.chat-box**
2. Remove **position:relative** from **.chat-time**
3. Style **#tail** with absolute positioning
4. Add some **padding-bottom** to **.chat-box**

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
div#chat-panel-casca {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition-delay: .6s;
    transition: .7s;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
div#chat-casca {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #F4F4F6;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 499px;
}
/*this stretch corresponds to a tail applied to the first balloon*/
div#chat-casca #tail {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0 17.5px 19px 17.5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #FFFFFF transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    filter: drop-shadow(-6px 2px 2px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.24));
    transform: rotate(48deg);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: 0;
    left: -19px;
}

div#chat-casca .chat-box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 323px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 12px;
    left: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166,166,166,0.60);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166,166,166,0.60);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166,166,166,0.60);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/*This is my main css, it is the balloon composition*/
div#chat-casca .chat-box p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
div#chat-casca .chat-box .chat-time {
    color: #4d4e53;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    padding-left: 293px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-casca">
   <div class="chat-box">
     <p>Hy, i ame here</p>
     <div id="tail"></div>
     <small class="chat-time">9:6</small>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-box">
     <p>Some text</p>
     <p> Another text.</p>
     <small class="chat-time">9:6</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

now another solution works for me

```css
div #chat-casca .chat-box {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 323px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /*add this line*/
  flex-flow: wrap; /*and this line*/
  margin-top: 12px;
  left: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
}
```

thanks everbody for try help me

Answer (score 0):

Your tail div is interfering with the chat box's height.
Rather than using an actual div for the tail, try adding a class to the existing chat-casca div when you need the tail.

```
  <div class="chat-box tail">
```

then add the ::before selector so it doesn't interfere with the other elements. Position this absolute and the chat-box positioned relative, then you can position the tail relative to the chat box.

```
  #chat-casca .tail::before {
   content: "";
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid #fff;
   border-top: 10px solid #fff;
   border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
   left: -19px;
   top: 0px;
   filter: drop-shadow(-4px 2px 2px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.24));
  }

  #chat-casca .chat-box {
   border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
   width: 323px;
   background-color: white;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-left: 45px;
   height: auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.60);
  }
```